# Error : `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\button.png'`

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

I use `FileUpload` in my `Asp.Net WebFrom`.
I upload any file with `C#` from computer.

```
 string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
 string str = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

`FileStream fs = new FileStream(str, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` `//` I get error in this row. Error : `Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\button.png'`.

And actually this is my file path : `'C:\Users\Ceyhun\Downloads\button.png'`.

Can anyone say that what can be problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is get the file name of the file uploaded by the client and trying to open a file with that file name. Because you're running IIS Express (which runs from c:\program files) your code looks for the file in that location and it doesn't exist.

The file exists on the client computer and the only way your code has access to it is via the FileUploadCOntrol.

You cannot directly reference the file from the client's computer.
The FileUpload control will give you the file contents in bytes or allow you to directly save the file on your server.

e.g.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
```

To get the file contents as a byte array:

```
byte[] fileBytes = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

Comment: I saved it on my server,
And now I would like to save it on  sql database.
Now I should add it from my server to sql database ?
And then it will remain in my server after adding to database ?
Sorry, may be I confused.

Comment: So the file upload control has the file contents in bytes. You don't need to store it in your web server necessarily. You could directly save the bytes into the db.